# In my Spring Boot app, how can I debug/tell why I am getting 302 errors?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am running Jmeter to do some load testing on my app.  When I run it with a single thread, I get all 200 codes in my test. Great.  But when I run 2 threads, I start getting 302 redirect errors on my second thread.  BUT that's not what I'm asking about.

How can I enable debug in my Spring Boot app in order to tell WHY I am getting these 302s?  In my application.properties I have tried:
`debug=true`
`logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.* = debug`
`logging.level.org.springframework.web.*=debug`
.. but those don't get me the info I'm looking for.  What else can I try to get more debug?

I can see the 302s in the Tomcat localhost_accersss_log.txt file, but no other info is there (as expected)

Comment: 302 isn't an error it indicates a redirect. A 4xx or 5xx response code is an error. Why you get them, just a guess but you are using Spring Security and login once and not on the other threads, leading to a redirect to the login page.

Comment: @M.Deinum yea I guess 'error' was the wrong choice of word, but yes using Spring Security.  I'm guessing that there is something wrong with our security config or something, but I feel like I'm pulling teeth with Spring to get helpful logging sometimes.  I think I'm going to implement AuthenticationFailureHandler and see if I can get more info from that.

Comment: As stated you are probably logging in once and not for the other threads, hence no session hence a redirect to login.